# How to detect failure to match variadic parameters to function parameter

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17

I'm writing a memory pool and have it working nicely. It automatically forwards the parameters used to call the function with to the object constructor when a new type must be allocated. (e.g. a matrix of a certain size and type)

What I would like to do is make a compile-time check on parameter types and count to avoid a strange error output but write one myself for either case.

Is it possible to check for this manually if I have a the object type and the <...Args> template parameters and values (Args ...args)

i.e. when calling

```
new_item = new T( std::forward<Args>( args )... );
```

My initial idea was to use sizeof..., but a constructor can have multiple implementations with different parameter counts. Can this be done using e.g. constexpressions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but maybe [`std::is_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) is what you are after.

Comment: I experimented a bit and just doing `new T( std::forward<Args>( args )... )` unchecked gives you a pretty decent error message when it fails. If you "check it" then your error message is just some fixed `static_assert` string that doesn't contain the information of what `T` and `Args` are.

Comment: @nwp I half agree. It depends on how deep the call is buried as the end error is in the calling function, and not the callee, which would be where I was hoping it would stop

Comment: If you have `T` and `args...` available earlier you can add `static_assert(sizeof(new T( std::forward<Args>( args )... )) > 0);` so you get the full error message without the call propagating further. Maybe add an error message too. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/653471610440407f).